# how to check a property is less than a specific value in mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have got the below JSON Array response

```
[
    {
        "StayDuration": 1,
    },
    {
        "StayDuration": 5,
    },
    {
        "StayDuration": 11,
    },
    {
        "StayDuration": 10,
    },
    {
        "StayDuration": 3,
    },
    {
        "StayDuration": 2,
    },
    {  
        "StayDuration": 6,
    },
]
```

I am using the mocha "chai-thing" and "chai-like" for testing whether the "StayDuration" value is less than "12" and the code is below

```
it("it should GET Device List with Good Auth Status", function(done) {
  chai.request('http://xxxxxx')
    .get('/xxxx/xxx/xxx')
    .set({ "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` })
    .then((res) => {
       res.should.have.status(200);
       res.should.be.json;
       res.body.should.be.an('array');
       res.body.should.all.have.property('StayDuration');
       res.body.StayDuration.should.all.be.below(12);
       done();
    }).catch((err) => done(err))
 });
```

When I run the test I am facing an error "Cannot read property 'should' of undefined". Can you please help me with it

Comment: If your error is in line `res.body.should...` then maybe `body` field doesn't exists into `res` object. Use `console.log()` to check that. If your response is as you have posted, there is not a field called `body`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res.body.StayDuration` is `undefined` because `StayDuration` is a property of *each Object* within the `res.body` Array and *not* a property of the `res.body` Array itself.

I do not know if chai/chai-things provides a way to test a property of each Object in an Array. However, a simple mapping of the body Objects to their `StayDuration` values would allow you to perform the test:

```
res.body.map((item) => item.StayDuration).should.all.be.below(12);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the solution and it works fine :)